# How do I download whole file system from a given Sharepoint site?

Tags: python, sharepoint, office365

So I have  a shaprepoint site with name "ABC". Below is the file structure in which files are stored in it:

```
|-Folder1
|  |--file_1_1.docx
|  |--file_1_2.docx
|
|-Folder2
|  |--file_2_1.docx
|
|-file_x.docx
```

Now I want to download the files to my local machine. I have heared that I can do this using "Office365-REST-Python-Client" lib. I have gone through different codes on internet but doesn't find any specific solution. Below is the code that gives me information about the all the flders but not about the files.

```
client_id = "XXXXX"
client_secret = "YYYY"

site_url = "https://tenantName.sharepoint.com/sites/ABC"
relative_url = "Documents"

def connectAuth():
    # Initialize the client credentials
    client_credentials = ClientCredential(client_id, client_secret)

    # create client context object
    ctx = ClientContext(site_url).with_credentials(client_credentials)
    
    try:
        libraryRoot = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_path(relative_url)
        libraryRoot.expand(["Files","Folders"]).get().execute_query()

        folder = libraryRoot.folders
        print(folder)
        
        print("Number of folders:", len(folder))
        print("Folder names:")
        for folder_item in folder:
            ctx.load(folder_item)
            ctx.execute_query()
            print(folder_item.properties["Name"])
            
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
        print('Problem printing out library contents')
        #sys.exit(1)

connectAuth()
```

Can you please help me out in downloading the files present in those folders as well as outside those folder. I mean I want files **file_1_1.docx, file_1_2.docx, file_2_1.docx and file_x.docx** to be downloaded to my local machine.